# Spring .Boot Mustache how to navigate a Java Map in the Model

Tags: java, spring-boot, mustache

I have a Map which has a key product code and the corresponding product name. I want to be able to use the map to lookup and display the product name using the product key. I do not know how to display that in mustache. I store the map in the Model object in a spring mvc app. It does have to be a map, but a map seems to be the most natural way to do the lookup. I don't know how else I can represent this with another convenient structure. I have shown my table snippet. How can I display the map? Is it even possible? "002022" -> "Banana" would be an example of an entry.

```
       @GetMapping("/products/display")
       public String displayProductsByCode(Model model){

         Map<String,String> m = repo.findProductsByCode();
         model.addAttribute("productLookup",m);
         return "productDisplay";
     }

   <table>
     <tr>
       <thead>
       <th> Product Code></th>
       <th> Product Name </th>
      </thead>
    </tr>
    {{# ????}}
     <tr>
     <td> ..I want the product code here</td>
     </tr>
    {{/ ???? }} 
   </table>
```

Answer (score 0):

Create a class for holding product code and product name and showing it to the view.

```
public class Product {
    private String code;
    private String name;


    public Product() {

    }

    public Product(String code, String name) {
        this.code = code;
        this.name = name;
    }

    public String getCode() {
        return code;
    }

    public void setCode(String code) {
        this.code = code;
    }
    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }
    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

}
```

In your controller create list of this Product type. How you implement getting all products is up to you. Here is the example:

```
@GetMapping("/product/display")
    public String displayProductByCode(Map<String, Object> model){
     //your logic here to retrieve products. Below simple example:
     List<Product> listForModel = new ArrayList<>();
     Product product1 = new Product("002022", "Banana");
     Product product2 = new Product("003033", "Mango");
     listForModel.add(product1);
     listForModel.add(product2);
     model.put("productsById", listForModel);
     return "index";

}
```

This is index.html file.

```
 <table cellspacing="10px">
        <tr>
            <th>Product Code</th>
            <th>Product Name</th>
        </tr>

        {{#productsById}}           
        <tr>
            <td>{{code}}</td>
            <td>{{name}}</td>
        </tr>
      {{/productsById}}
    </table>
```

Comment: Thank you but I had figured it out. I wanted to find out if there was a way to do it with a map with key,value pairs, but then ended up using an object.